# High CPU usage in teleconferencing with screen sharing on Linux with Intel graphics

Tags: linux, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have an `Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)` (actually it's a Dell Latitude 5420). The system runs Debian 12 "bookworm" (**update**: I'm using GNOME on X11). I have package `intel-media-va-driver-non-free` installed. I can see (with `lsof`) that Google Chrome has the package's `iHD_drv_video.so` open, and so does Zoom. But teleconferencing uses too much CPU. Jitsi on Google Chrome is a pain, and with screen sharing the system becomes almost unusable. With Zoom it's a bit better, but it's still quite slow.

If this can't be solved with software, can it be solved with hardware? For example, are there any Thunderbolt graphics cards with suitable drivers?

**Update:**

I took a look at the `top` and `intel-gpu-top` during a jitsi conference where I was sharing. The GPU "Render/3D" "Busy" value was varying between 50-70% (the other values, "Blitter", "Video" and "VideoEnhance" are at zero). CPU was also varying between 20-80%. (There was 3.3 GB unused RAM.)

(Note that a CPU usage of 50% is practically full CPU usage, since it has two threads per core. 50% is practically the maximum CPU usage for which the system will perform decently.)

The problem is that it varies (as I said, from 20%, which is OK, to 80%, which sucks), and it's not clear to me what affects it. By looking at the numbers it's also not clear that the problem is screen sharing. It's more like it's my video, the others' video, my audio, the others' audio, and the screen sharing, that add up together. It may be that I perceive screen sharing as the problem because it's the straw that breaks the camel's back.

Comment: Theoretically, you could get yourself a TB4 External GPU enclosure, but your iGPU should be more than capable to handle Zoom and Jitsi. A external TB4 GPU enclosure likely will not solve your issue. What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using GNOME on X11.

Comment: is it the CPU usage or the iGPU usage which is too high ? Which CPU do you have, i5 or i7? also, how much RAM do you have installed? Are you sure it's not a paging issue?

Comment: @1NN I don't know how to check the iGPU usage, so I'm talking about the CPU usage, which I check with `top`. My RAM is 16 GB and there's typically plenty of free RAM. The CPU is a 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz.

Comment: @1NN I added some info to the question. I continue to investigate.

Comment: Have you tried using ```gamemode```? For me on my mid-2011 iMac that I have running openSUSE Tumbleweed, sometimes running the application with gamemode helps it. Failing that, try running it on a lighter WM then report back.

Comment: this thread might help: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/qul5e7/prevent_zoom_from_consuming_all_your_cpu_on_linux/

Comment: Hi @AntonisChristofides, are there any news??? Have you tried my answer? Does the problem still persists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by accident, while experimenting with another graphics-intensive application. At times it was working fine, but at other times its CPU usage inexplicably increased without reason—so did the CPU usage of all other processes—while its GPU usage dropped sharply.

I upgraded the BIOS of my Dell Latitude 5420 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Zoom, you should try and toggle "Hardware acceleration": [Link](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360037870291-Managing-advanced-video-settings) - the KB says that it will consume more resources the more incoming-videos you have.

The setting should probably be disabled, but if it's already so - try to enable it.

I am not familiar with Jitsi, but you can toggle "Hardware acceleration" for chrome itself: [Link](https://pureinfotech.com/disable-hardware-acceleration-chrome/)

HA will help when you have a dedicated GPU but might cause problems with onboard-ones.